# Trouble Multithreading a Kivy applciation

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, kivy

I'm trying to have the application UI continue to run even while the BLE scan function is running which is asynchronous. I tried creating another thread but, the UI still freezes when I use the activate button. The screen in question is Screen4, the rest is unimportant. I've tried a couple of different methods to get it to work but I'm having trouble implementing some of the example with it either producing an error or just still causing the UI to freeze for a couple of seconds. Here's the code:

````
import sys
import json
import googlemaps
import pygatt
import time
import asyncio
from bleak import discover
from urllib.request import urlopen
from twilio.rest import Client
from threading import Thread

#UI import libraries
from kivy.app import App
from  kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.clock import Clock

accSID = '**********'
authtkn = '*********'
twilcli = Client(accSID, authtkn)
sendNum = '********'

key = '*********'
url = 'http://ipinfo.io/json'
i = 0


sm = ScreenManager()

class Screen1(Screen):
    def pair_pressed(self):

        def BLEdetect (self):
            async def run():
                devices = await discover()
                for d in devices:
                    print(d)
                    k = 0
                    if (str(d).find('DSD TECH') != -1):
                        global address
                        address = str(d)[0:18]
                        print(address)
                        sm.current = 's2'
                        k = 1
                        break
                    if (k != 1):
                        k = 0
                        sm.current = 's3'

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(run())

        Clock.schedule_once(BLEdetect, 0.5)

class Screen2(Screen):
    def submit_pressed(self):

        contact1_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        contact1 = StringProperty('')
        self.contact1 = self.contact1_inp.text

        phone1_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        phone1 = StringProperty('')
        self.phone1 = self.phone1_inp.text
    #----------------------------------------------------------------
        contact2_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        contact2 = StringProperty('')
        self.contact2 = self.contact2_inp.text

        phone2_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        phone2 = StringProperty('')
        self.phone2 = self.phone2_inp.text
    #---------------------------------------------------------------
        contact3_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        contact3 = StringProperty('')
        self.contact3 = self.contact3_inp.text

        phone3_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        phone3 = StringProperty('')
        self.phone3 = self.phone3_inp.text
    #--------------------------------------------------------------
        contact4_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        contact4 = StringProperty('')
        self.contact4 = self.contact4_inp.text

        phone4_inp = ObjectProperty(None)
        phone4 = StringProperty('')
        self.phone4 = self.phone4_inp.text
    #-------------------------------------------------------------
        global contactlst
        contactlst = [[self.contact1, self.phone1], [self.contact2, self.phone2],
                      [self.contact3, self.phone3],[self.contact4, self.phone4]]

        #if contaclst is None:


        j = 0
        while (j < 4):
            print("Contact " + str(j + 1) + ": " + contactlst[j][0])
            print("Phone " + str(j + 1) + ": " + contactlst[j][1])
            j += 1

        sm.current = 's4' 

class Screen3(Screen):
    def tryagain_pressed(self):
        sm.current = 's1'

    def cancel_pressed(self):
        exit()

class Screen4(Screen):

    stop = threading.Event()

    global BLEscan, i

    def BLEscan(self):
        while (i == 0):
            async def run():
                devices = await discover()
                for d in devices:
                    print(d)
                    k = 0
                    if (str(d).find(address) != -1):
                        response = urlopen(url)
                        data = json.load(response)


                        city = data['city']
                        loc = data['loc']
                        country = data['country']
                        region = data['region']
                        gmapurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='
                        gmapurl = gmapurl + loc + '&size=600x600&zoom=14&sensor=true&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C' + loc + '&key=' + key

                        def waste_time(dt):
                            pass

                        while ((k < 4) and (contactlst[k][0] != '')):
                            mes = 'Please Send Help ' + contactlst[k][0]
                            info = '{4} \nRegion : {1} \nCountry : {2} \nCity : {3} \nLoc: {0}'.format(loc,region,country,city,mes)
                            message = twilcli.messages.create(body=info, from_=sendNum, to=contactlst[k][1], media_url= gmapurl)

                            Clock.schedule_once(waste_time, 3)

                            k += 1
                        i = 1
                        break

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(run())

    def second_thread(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(BLEscan, 5)

    def activate_pressed (self):
        i = 0
        threading.Thread(target=self.second_thread).start()

    def deactivate_pressed(self):
        i = 1




class esosApp(App):
    def on_stop(self):
        self.root.stop.set()

    def build(self):

        screenone = Screen1(name='s1')
        screentwo = Screen2(name='s2')
        screenthree = Screen3(name='s3')
        screenfour = Screen4(name='s4')

        sm.add_widget(screenone)
        sm.add_widget(screentwo)
        sm.add_widget(screenthree)
        sm.add_widget(screenfour)

        return sm    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    esosApp().run()```
````

Comment: Don't use `Clock.schedule_once()`. That specifically runs the scheduled code on the main thread. Exactly what you do not want.

Comment: And `Clock.schedule_interval()` does the same.